# Any alternatives to `INET6_ATON` SQL function, but in Python?

Tags: python, php

I want to convert a PHP program that uses MySQL to Python.
I found a way to store the database but I need to find a Pythonic alternative to the `INET6_ATON` SQL function.
Can someone help me, please?

Comment: You mean [`ipaddress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html)?

Comment: What's the problem about using MySQL? Did you choose a different database for the Python version?

Comment: Extending @tadman suggestion, you need to access [`.packed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html#ipaddress.IPv4Address.packed) attribute to get `bytes` representation. E.g. `ip_address("10.0.0.1").packed` or `ip_address("48f3::d432:1431:ba23:845f").packed`.

Comment: I dont like MySQL so i use annother way to store data.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Extending @tadman suggestion, you need to access .packed attribute to get bytes representation. E.g. ip_address("10.0.0.1").packed or ip_address("48f3::d432:1431:ba23:845f").packed.

[from Olvin Roght]

Thanks its doing exactly the same thing !

Docs of ipaddress.IPv4Address.packed:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html#ipaddress.IPv4Address.packed

Comment: Please, format the answer correspondingly (and formulate the questions as short as possible). Cleaner answers and questions in same stype help readers.